# Half Life Model question from The Model Thinker - suspecting a book typo

Tags: mathematical-modeling

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PAwFV.png)Based on the Half Life Model, if a movie won an Oscar in 2016, and people's memories have a half life of two years, in 2018, what is the proportion of people who would still remember the movie?

Question from the book 'The Model Thinker'.

The author says the answer is 1/4. But don't understand how this can be?

The half life is 2 years, and 2016-2018 is two years, it follows that 1/2 would have forgotten the movie in 2018.

Also, substituting the t = 2, H = 2
t = 2 years from 2016
H = half life of 2 years

The equation will yield 1/2

Comment: Well, that does appear to be a typo but it is so blatant that I expect there is a misunderstanding.  Can you print the relevant passage exactly as it appears, with no edits or omissions?

Comment: Here it is: https://i.stack.imgur.com/PAwFV.png

Comment: Yeah, that looks like a typo.  Perhaps the author meant to say that the half life was one year.  In any case, your calculation is correct.

Comment: Think so too. Thanks for validating! Finding a way to contact the author / publisher.